# jquery Variable In Head

Tags: jquery, tags, head

I would like to have a script in the head like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="scriptid" src="https://accountName.cloudServiceURL.com"></script>
```

I would like to make the "accountName" to be able to be changed depending on the person using the template file.

So I have created a variable like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var claccount = 'accountName';
</script>
```

So then I am trying to use this to let folks add their own account name like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="scriptid" src="https://' + accountName + '.cloudServiceURL.com"></script>
```

Does jQuery prevent doing this type of thing with scripts because I do this all the time with anchors and other things.

I have also tried to insert a script tag into the head using jquery but it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: You're trying to use a *javascript* variable **outside of script** . What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the script dynamically.  Instead of having the separate script tag in the head for the script in question, you can load it dynamically when you resolve the account name like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var claccount = 'accountName';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'scriptId';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://' + claccount + '.cloudServiceURL.com';
    // you may need this as well...
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)​;​​​
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution but I can not get it to work.

Comment: I apologize.  The variable name was incorrect. Also, you may need the last line of code. I changed my answer.

Comment: I was just reading about that as I saw your answer.However,that is throwing this error "SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'â' instead"

Comment: Ok ... I got it now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. You were very helpful!

Comment: no problem. If you have anymore difficulty getting this code to work you can check the demo at - http://jsfiddle.net/vT9DZ/3/